# ModuleNotFoundError while executing a bazel script

Tags: python, build, bazel, modulenotfounderror

I have a python file `main.py` in which I am importing github package [import github]
I have created a build file as follows:

```
py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

When I run this through Bazel command, `bazel run: main`, I am getting **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'**.

Can someone please tell how to include python libraries inside build file and run through Bazel?

**Note:** I have already installed github (version: 1.2.7) through Python and it is getting updated using pip list from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can build the python basic bazel example using this [link](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/examples/py/BUILD) for Bazel Python code build. This. is a good reference to start a [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9GpV_K17xo)